# withContext(Dispatchers.IO) infinitely blocking after running

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to coroutines, and I am trying to load in several files from internal storage on `Dispatchers.IO` along with some other things. So I am starting a coroutine and then calling several suspend functions each of which uses `withContext` to read its file. But in the first function, `withContext` runs its code and never returns, so the rest of the coroutine never gets run. Is there something special about `withContext` or `Dispatchers.IO` which I am missing?

```
class MainViewModel(
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {


    private val liveSettings: MutableLiveData<Settings>

    suspend fun loadSettings(context: Context): Settings = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var settings: Settings
        try {
            context.openFileInput(FileManager.settingsDir).use { stream ->
                val jsonData = stream.readBytes().decodeToString()
                settings = Json.decodeFromString(Settings.serializer(), jsonData)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException){
            settings = Settings(mutableListOf(), mutableListOf())
        }
        Log.d("MainViewModel", "Loading Settings")     // this line is run
        settings
    }



    init{
        Log.i("MainViewModel", "ViewModel Constructed")
        liveSettings = MutableLiveData()


        viewModelScope.launch {
            Log.d("MainViewModel", "constructor coroutine started")
            liveSettings.value = loadSettings(getApplication())
            Log.d("MainViewModel", "Hello")            // this line is not run

            // other stuff...

        }
    }
}
```

I expect an output like

```
ViewModel Constructed
constructor coroutine started
Loading Settings
Hello
```

but the output is

```
ViewModel Constructed
constructor coroutine started
Loading Settings
```

Comment: In the code u shared, does "Hello" get printed when you remove `withContext` function call?

Comment: The function no longer blocks if I change `viewModelScope.launch {` to `viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.Default) {` AND I move my settings variable outside of the `MutableLiveData` object (apparently `MutableLiveData`s do not like being changed apart from the main thread. But I still don't understand what difference that makes to the inner `withContext`. Does plain `.launch{` make the coroutine run on the main thread?

Comment: I can’t see anything wrong with the code you’ve posted. I wonder if you’ve commented something out or deleted something you didn’t think was relevant but actually is. `viewModelScope.launch` uses the main thread by default, yes. Your use of `withContext` as shown above is correct. There might be some code elsewhere blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that that the app is crashing and you don't realize it. Double check logcat. [You cannot set a live data value outside the main thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#setvalue). You should use `postValue` instead:

```
    viewModelScope.launch {
        Log.d("MainViewModel", "constructor coroutine started")

        // This is launched on an non UI thread - use postValue
        liveSettings.postValue(loadSettings(getApplication()))

        Log.d("MainViewModel", "Hello")            // this line is not run

        // other stuff...

    }
```

Comment: `viewModelScope` uses Dispatchers.Main by default so this code is called on the main thread. `postValue` shouldn’t be necessary.